# Reduced power of an ordered field

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory, fields, ordered-fields

Suppose $K$ is an ordered field, $X$ is any set, and $F$ is a filter over $X$.  Let $G$ be the reduced power of $K$ by $F$.  That is, we take all functions from $X$ to $K$, then take equivalence classes by $F$.  We compute all operations and the ordering of $G$ modulo $F$.  (Note $F$ could be the trivial filter $\{ X \}$, in which case we just have a power of $K$.)

It is easy to check that $G$ is a characteristic-zero commutative ring, but we may lose the totality of the ordering and get zero divisors.

**Question:** Is there a well-known first-order axiomatization for the kind of structure as $G$, which is preserved under further reduced powers?

Comment: So you're asking for a subtheory of ordered fields that is closed under reduced powers?

Comment: The sentences preserved by reduced products are exactly the Horn sentences. Thus, you are asking for an axiomatization of the Horn sentences valid in ordered fields. I’m not sure whether there is a complete characterization, but clearly these include the axioms of von Neumann regular lattice-ordered commutative rings.

Comment: Sorry, I misread power as product. But anyway, the axiomatization has to include what I wrote above.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes but a nontrivial one that still does some work.  We can abstractly define it as the intersection of all such theories, but I’m wondering if there’s a well-studied axiomatization.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks, this is helpful.